# will look out over a capital city

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "will look out over a capital city" mean "will keep watch on a capital city"?  The prepositional word "over" has given me a hard time to figure out what it means. Because a phrase like "look over one's shoulders" is very different in meaning with "look on one's shoulders."

> Stay home, Americans were exhorted, to prevent further spread of a surging virus that has claimed 400,000 American lives. Biden **will look out over a capital city** dotted with empty storefronts that attest to the pandemic’s deep economic toll and where summer protests laid bare the nation’s renewed reckoning on racial justice.

> Source:  [The Associated Press](https://apnews.com/article/biden-inauguration-joe-biden-capitol-siege-coronavirus-pandemic-immigration-a01d1ffa7862661914cb92b22e359854)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Look out over** means 'look from a high viewpoint at [the scene below]'. The writer envisages Mr Biden standing at a White House upper window looking out over Washington. (I've never been to Washington, but I imagine he would not literally be able to see details of the streets from there.)

Comment: Yes.. *look over* has special meaning for text or a list of details, or even some set of details of some kind, but it stems from being "higher" somehow

Comment: The phrase could have the other meaning, if you were talking about, say, Batman.  But I don't think anyone expects the President to be *literally* keeping watch over the city.